# AngularJS: if ng-model is filled by another model, how to make it affects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example, I have this:

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="model_1" value="{{model_2}}" />
    Show me {{model_1}}
```

The problem is that when model_2 is changed, the "Show me {{model_1}}" does not change to the new value.

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to do that?

Comment: If you want two variables with the same value, why dont use a single one instead?

Comment: I know that someone will asked this question. But I did not expect to get down votes from what I tried to make the question as simple as possible.

Comment: The reason is that actually value="{{model_2}}" is not a single module ,it actually is value="{{model_2}}{{model_3}}".

Comment: I hope this comment will make down-voter more happy.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to accomplish. I'm not sure why you'd be wanting to have 2 or 3 different model values assigned to the same input.

Comment: It would be a long story. I will try again to explain "as simple as" possible, but not too much simple. Let imagine that you have predefined values as dropdown (model_2 and model_3) and you want to show those selected values in the text field so that the user can edit further. Actually.... my case is a lot more complex than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="model_2" />
 Show me <span ng-bind="model_1" />
```

And in your controller

```
 scope.$watch('model_2', function() {
    scope.model_1 = scope.model_2
 });
```

UPDATE: since you really want to have one scope property to be sum of two others, you need to watch them both

```
 scope.$watch('model_1', updateModel3);
 scope.$watch('model_2', updateModel3);

 function updateModel3(){ 
   scope.model_3 = scope.model_1 + scope.model_2
 }
```

with markup

```
 <input ng-model='model_1' />
 <input ng-model='model_2' />
 <span ng-bind='model_3' />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not exactly what I want. Up vote for you anyways.

Comment: @SurasinTancharoen consider putting information from your comment into question, as it is really different issue.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, setting the `value` or `ng-value` will not change the model. You need to assign the `model_1` with the new value. You can do

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model_2" ng-change="model_1 = model_2"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="model_1"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

With AngularJS, you shouldn't be needing to use the `value` attribute. `ng-model`takes care of displaying the value for you. In my experience, having `ng-model` and `value` on the same tag has always resulted in a conflict. One of them will be ignored, and it seems that `value` is usually the one that is ignored.